# Can I inject a perl sub in a package?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'd like to be able to "inject" methods in a class on the fly, similarly to what happens with Mojolicious helpers. Something like this:

```
my $s = SomeThing->new;

$s->helper(do_this => sub {
               my $self = shift;
               $foo = shift;
           });

$s->do_this('bar');
```

I've made it some distance, but I would like the subs that get injected to be operating in the namespace of the class they get injected into, not in the `main` one. In other words this currently works as follows:

```
$s->do_this('bar');

print 'in main:      ', $foo;
```

this prints "bar" - and I'd like it not to, while I'd like *this*

```
print 'in SomeThing: ', $SomeThing::foo;
```

to print "bar" instead

while this works but seems clunky to me

```
$s->helper(do_this => sub {
               my $self = shift;
               ${(ref $self) . '::foo'} = shift;
           });

$s->do_this('foo');

print 'in SomeThing: ', $SomeThing::foo;  # now this prints "foo"
```

The package where all this happens looks like this:

```
package SomeThing {
    use Mojo::Base -base;
    use Carp;

    sub helper {
        my $self = shift;
        my $name = shift || croak "The helper name is required";
        my $sub = shift || sub {};

        my $namespace = __PACKAGE__;
        no strict 'refs';
        { 
            *{"$namespace\::$name"} = $sub
        }
    }
};
```

Is there a way to do this? I suspect I'd be messing up strictness real bad - but I kind of don't want to give up just yet (and it'd be a nice trick to learn).

Comment: Is it acceptable in your use-case to use `eval` to generate the code from a string?

Comment: Tip: Re "*`*{"$namespace\::$name"} = $sub`*", `*$name = $sub` would suffice here.

Comment: @pmqs I wanted to avoid that as far as possible

Comment: not clear to me from the question if you want the injected methods to just work for that instance or for any instance

Comment: They did say "package" and "class", not "object".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking to change the package associated with an already-compiled anon sub for the purpose of variable lookups. I don't know if that's possible.

Even if it was possible, it's not something you want to do because your code still wouldn't work. You'd have to add `use vars qw( foo );` to the file in which the `sub { }` literal is found. And that's in addition to using `our $foo;` or `use vars qw( $foo );` in `Something.pm` if you accessed it there.

That's pretty magical and messy. And it's easily avoided by using accessors. Simple replace

```
$s->helper(
   do_this => sub {
      my $self = shift;
      $foo = shift;
   },
);
```

with

```
$s->helper(
   do_this => sub {
      my $self = shift;
      $self->foo(shift);
   },
);
```

If you also need to add the accessor, you can use the following:

```
$s->helper(
   foo => sub {
      shift;
      state $foo;
      $foo = shift if @_;
      $foo
   },
   do_this => sub {
      my $self = shift;
      $self->foo(shift);
   },
);
```

---

As an aside, `monkey_patch` from [Mojo::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Util) can be used as a replacement for `helper`. (Credit to @brian d foy for bringing it up.) It does the same thing, but it has the two added benefits:

1. You don't need to support it.
2. It sets the name of the anon sub so that stack traces use a meaningful name instead of `__ANON__`.

Switching to `monkey_patch` doesn't address your problem, but I do recommend using it (or similar) in addition to the change of approach I mentioned above.

```
use Mojo::Util qw(  );
sub helper { shift; Mojo::Util::monkey_patch(__PACKAGE__, @_); }
```

Comment: I didn't say it could be a replacement for `helper`, just that it might be relevant. Since my answer didn't go into any depth and after rereading the question I still don't understand the problem, I just deleted my low quality answer. Typically, if I've seen that @ikegami has seen a question but not answered it, I try to leave something just so people don't think we ignored them.

Comment: @brian d foy, Re "*I didn't say it could be a replacement for helper*", Sorry, I was just trying to give credit. I've rephrased the text in question.

Comment: @brian d foy, Re "*I still don't understand the problem,*", `sub {
               my $self = shift;
               $foo = shift;
           }` should "magically" become `sub {
               my $self = shift;
               ${(ref $self) . '::foo'} = shift;
           }`, which is to say `$foo` should lookup `$foo` in the package into which the method was installed, not the package into which the code was compiled.

Comment: That's not the problem. That's the way the person is trying to solve some unstated problem.

Comment: @brian d foy, For sure. Using an accessor is very likely to address that, whatever it is.

Comment: @ikegami - thanks for your answer. I haven't had time to try out the solution yet (this is not my day job, just a fun side thing). I'll check, comment and accept ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Consider [roles](https://metacpan.org/pod/Role::Tiny).

```
# role module
package SomeThing::Role::Foo;
use Role::Tiny;
sub foo { 42 }
1;

# user
use strict;
use warnings;
use SomeThing;
use With::Roles;

my $something_with_foo = SomeThing->with::roles('+Foo');
# new subclass of SomeThing, doesn't affect other usage of SomeThing
my $obj = $something_with_foo->new;

# can also dynamically apply to an existing object
my $obj = SomeThing->new->with::roles('+Foo');
print $obj->foo;
```